# OpenCV Contours - need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to implement contours using the following code..

```
im = cv2.imread('C:\Users\Prashant\Desktop\T.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv2.drawContour(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('Image1',img)
```

but i am continously getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Prashant/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 17, in <module>
    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

do the function findContours need more arguments?
wht could i do to correct it.

Comment: Your syntax is actually correct for OpenCV 3.0-beta or later, but you are probably using a stable version 2.8 or something.

Comment: The behaviour is different across different versions of OpenCV (OpenCV2, 3, 4). I have answered it in detail below.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In OpenCV 2, [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) returns just two values, `contours` and `hierarchy`.  The error occurs when python tries to assign those two values to the three names given on left in this statement:

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Thanks Warren. It helped alot. :)

Answer (score 5):

It now returns three values:

```
findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

return image, contours, hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

**findContours** returns just three values image, contours and hierarchy in **opencv3**

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 3):

As of the year 2019, we have three versions of OpenCV (OpenCV2, OpenCV3, and OpenCV4).

OpenCV4 and OpenCV2 have similar behavoiur (of returning two values from `cv2.findContours`). Whereas OpenCV3 returns three values.

```
if cv2.getVersionMajor() in [2, 4]:
    # OpenCV 2, OpenCV 4 case
    contour, hier = cv2.findContours(
                    thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
else:
    # OpenCV 3 case
    image, contour, hier = cv2.findContours(
                    thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Comment: i have opencv3.4.4 , i have written three return values it still gets error  _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.4) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:195: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'
how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

- findContours returns only two values. so use just,

So use

```
contours, hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: result will be saved in contours

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),
                                              cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Python version 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

NumPy version: 1.16.1

argparse version: 1.1

CV2 version: 4.0.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "omr.py", line 254, in <module>

    main()

  File "omr.py", line 237, in main

    answers, im = get_answers(args.input)

  File "omr.py", line 188, in get_answers

    contours = get_contours(im)

  File "omr.py", line 26, in get_contours

    im2, contours, hierarchy =cv2.findContours(image_gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

This is resolved by removing 'im2 ,' from line 26.. as in OpenCv version 3.0 or higher, the function 'findContours' returns only 2 values.. so the statement should be

```
contours, hierarchy =cv2.findContours(image_gray,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and also upgrade your OpenCv version

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OpenCV version, `cv2.findContours()` has varying return signatures. In OpenCV 3.4.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) returns 3 items. In OpenCV 2.X and 4.1.X, [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) returns 2 items

You can easily obtain the contours regardless of the version like this:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Current Opencv Versions **cv2.findContours** returns 2 Values and that is Contours and heirachy. Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points (along the boundary), having same color or intensity. The contours are a useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition.